# HTML/CSS How to wrap an image with another (Liquid Layout)?

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, liquid-layout

For a portfolio, I need to wrap all images with a computer image for presentation. I'm going to use something like this example to wrap images:

[image]

Images must have fluid dimensions (height & width in percent), so the wrapper too..

Anyone has an idea about how to achieve that?

Is there a way to do it cross-browser way?

Answer (score 6):

Add the image as a `background-image` of a reziseable `<div>` and append a second div with another backgrund image.

like:

```
<div class="laptop-bg">
  <div class="laptop-content-bg"></div>
</div>

.laptop-bg
{
   background-image:url(...);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width:100%;
   background-size: contain;
   background-clip: border-box;
   position:relative;
}

.laptop-bg > .laptop-content-bg
{
   background-image: url(...);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   position: absolute;
   /* % to outer border */
   left: 6%;
   top: 6%;
   bottom: 6%;
   right: 6%;
}
```

Update: I did not think about the inner spaceing on rezising. You should try to estimate the distance between content and outer in percentage.

Update:

The best thing you can do, is to add the background-image as `<img>` in the document. Not as a background-grafik. This will be your canvas to place a inner div:

```
<div class="laptop-bg">
    <div class="laptop-content-bg"> 
    </div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS7Xm.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
  /* Like pointed out by @Pio, you should add a max-width*/
   .laptop-bg
   {
       max-width: 1000px;
   }


.laptop-bg img
{
    max-width: 100%;
}

.laptop-bg > .laptop-content-bg
{
   /* background-image(url:...); */
   background-color:blue;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   position: absolute;
   /* % to outer border */
   left:17.5%;
   top: 17%;
   bottom: 22%;
   right: 18.5%;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kq7ym/3/

Comment: That's working as long as the wrapper image fills the whole width. If the page is wider than the laptop image, the content still resizes...

Comment: That is correct. `.laptop-bg { max-width: 1000px; }` should handle that.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i would follow this way :

1) create laptop monitor-like div - Its just a div with thick black border + top left and top right rounded borders + 2 elements (green point and reflection) you can create it with CSS or use images.

2) create bottom part of laptop - Its also rounded div + shadow + cavity

Comment: This approach seems good (and IE8 friendly). Can you share an example. Ok for the top and bottom of computer. But what about left/right borders?

Comment: @118218, here is the prototype - http://jsfiddle.net/v8V2g/1/ . Then depends what browser you are going to support. If you need IE < 8 - then need to change border-radius with images , change :after with extra tags and use images instead of border-radius.