# Align HTML element with background img positioned center

Tags: html, css

I have a background image center positioned on the body like so:

```
body {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../img/backgroundMd.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed #000; 
}
```

I want to align a div a part of the image. So it exactly covers it (on different screen resolutions)

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 320px;
    background-color: black;
    top: ?
    left: ?
}
```

The backgroundMD.jpg is very large, so it goes off the screen. Thats why I can't make a wrapper div and center that. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or sketchout what you are trying to do? If the background image is to large you could perhaps try `background-size:cover`?

Comment: At best you could use % based position values but I suspect you would have a lot of issues when re-sizing the screen.

Comment: I've experimented with this in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829610/html-css-how-to-wrap-an-image-with-another-liquid-layout/21829770#21829770

With the conclusion, that the best thing you can do is to append the `<img>` to the DOM to use it as a canvas.

Answer (score 4):

If the divs dimensions are fixed you can do something like this

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 320px;
    background-color: black;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -200px 0 0 -165px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can not know how height the image in the background will be if it's scaled to the viewport. You will have to add the background as a `<img>` element. Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/dLBdv/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-canvas">
        <p>Nice to sea you</p>
    </div>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/1000x500" /> 
</div>


.container
{
    position: relative;
}
.container > img
{
    max-width: 100%;
}

.container > .container-canvas
{
   background-color:blue;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   position: absolute;
   /* % to outer border */
   left:10%;
   top: 10%;
   bottom: 10%;
   right: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to play with this dimension - this will help you to keep your element in middle of page

```
div {margin:0 auto;
     width:400px;
     height: 320px;
     background-color: black;}
```

Comment: you will have to play with margin e.g. margin:100px or 200px auto; if you make fiddle  we can help you